# Name of method same as class, what does it mean?

Tags: c#

Need help. I couldn't figure out why there's no error.

```
public class DerivedPoint 
{
    public DerivedPoint(string fName, string Name, double sallary)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a constructor. Something so basic, every C# tutorial covers it

Comment: That's a constructor. I suggest you to read a tutorial on C#'s syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

> A constructor is a method whose name is the same as the name of its
>   type. Its method signature includes only the method name and its
>   parameter list; it does not include a return type. The following
>   example shows the constructor for a class named Person.

```
public class Person
{
   private string last;
   private string first;

   public Person(string lastName, string firstName)
   {
      last = lastName;
      first = firstName;
   }

   // Remaining implementation of Person class.
}
```